# Getting wrong output values- Basic C Loops assignment

Tags: c, loops

Assignment 3: Acme Travel Agency

Problem Statement

After a successful career solving all of the world’s toughest cryptography problems for Acme Cryptography Division, you have decided that you want to see the world. This is why you’ve requested a transfer to work for the Acme Travel Agency.

The Acme Travel Agency specializes in airline travel, and due to your quality assurance experience, you are assigned to analyze the quality of different flight plans. A flight plan consists of N connecting flights. After each flight except for the last one, there is a layover period in which the passenger must wait for the next flight. You have been tasked to calculate the destination time (without taking into account time zone changes), as well as the quality of the flight plan.

If the total time that a passenger is flying as at least two times greater than the time in layover, a flight plan is considered to be efficient. Otherwise, a flight plan is considered to be inefficient.

To calculate the destination time, add the total trip duration (the sum of all flight a layover durations) to the departure time, and calculate the corresponding time in a 24-hour clock format. Note that flight plans may last overnight, or may have a duration greater than a day. As an example, if a flight plan departed at 09:30 and lasted for 2000 minutes (that’s a long flight plan!), the destination time would be 18:50 the next day. As such, you would report 18:50 as the destination time.

Input Specification

Input will begin with a line single integer, N (1

Output Specification

Your program should output the arrival time and the quality of the flight. This should be formatted in the following way:

This flight plan is S, and will conclude at HH:MM.

where S is a string: either “efficient” or “inefficient” depending on the quality of the flight as defined in the Problem Statement. HH:MM is the 24-hour time of the destination as defined in the Problem Statement.

Sample I/O

Input:

1
7 45
75

Output:

This flight plan is efficient, and will conclude at 09:00.

Input:

2
13 30
75 180
85

Output:

This flight plan is inefficient, and will conclude at 19:10.

Input:

3
12 27
500 300
600 400
300

Output:

This flight plan is efficient, and will conclude at 23:27.

Deliverables

For your submission, please submit to webcourses2 a single file containing your source code. For scoring guidelines, please refer to the section labeled ‘Scoring Rubric’.

This assignment is due on webcourses2 at 11:59 PM, 21 February, 2013.

As a hint, it is easiest to handle time by keeping track of the minute of the day, modulo 1440 (the number of minutes in a day). Then, when printing the time, the hour is the minute of the day divided by 60, and the minute is the minute of the day modulo 60.

Scoring Rubric

This program is scored out of 20 points.

Coding Style (9) points
(1) Program contains a complete header comment (name, date, brief summary)
(1) Program includes meaningful internal comments
(1) Program maintains a reasonable use of whitespace
(1) Program uses clear, descriptive variable names
(1) Program reads in all values as integers
(1) Program contains a loop over N (or some function of N)
(1) Program does NOT prompt the user for input
(1) Program contains an if statement for comparing the flight time and layover time.
(1) Program correctly uses printf percent codes to print the time (%02d)

Correctness of Output (11) points (partial credit is possible)
(10) Five Test cases, (2) points per case
(1) Program prints the correct efficiency rating (efficient, inefficient)
(1) Program prints the correct destination time, regardless of formatting
(1) Text is exactly of the specified form.

My code:

```
// Included libraries
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

// Integer declaration
int N, hours, mins, i, flight, layover, finflight, flighttot=0, layovertot=0;

// N, hours, mins input scan
scanf("%d", &N);
scanf("%d %d", &hours, &mins);

// N loop, flight and layover input
for(i=0; i<N-1; i++) {
scanf("%d %d", &flight, &layover);
flighttot += flight;
layovertot += layover;
}

// Final flight input scan
scanf("%d", &finflight);
flighttot += finflight;

// Equations
mins += (hours*60)+flighttot+layovertot;
hours == mins/60;
hours %= 24;
mins %= 60;

// Output
if(flighttot >= 2*layovertot)
printf("The flight plan is efficient, and will conclude at %d:%d",&hours, &mins);

else
printf("The flight plan is inefficient, and will conclude at %d:%d",&hours, &mins);

return 0;
}
```

Any help fixing my program would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We are not your homework doers.

Comment: Shorten up your question, tell us what your specific problems are, and show us where you're having specific difficulty.  As it is right now, this is a total junk question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hours == mins/60;
```

This is wrong (in your program).

`==` is the equality operator, but you are looking for the assignment operator `=`:

```
hours = mins/60;
```

Then:

```
printf("The flight plan is efficient, and will conclude at %d:%d",&hours, &mins)
```

This is wrong. There is no point of using the `&` operator here, what you want is:

```
printf("The flight plan is efficient, and will conclude at %d:%d",hours, mins)
```

(Same for your other `printf` call).

Please enable the warnings in your compiler and fix all the warnings.